# Collapsible menu with sub-header

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm adding a collapsible FAQ's page on my website using some code taken from W3Schools. However, I would like to be able to have the collapsible questions also sit on a collapsible sub-heading.

For Example:

Postage rates > (click to open list of questions)
How much to send to Europe? > (Click to reveal answer)

I've tried wrapping a section within a section in the HTML and whilst this works for the first step (sub-heading) the then revealed question being clicked on does not reveal the answer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    .collapsible {
      background-color: #777;
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 18px;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    .active, .collapsible:hover {
      background-color: #555;
    }

    .collapsible:after {
      content: '\002B';
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      float: right;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }

    .active:after {
      content: "\2212";
    }

    .content {
      padding: 0 18px;
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h2>Animated Collapsibles</h2>

    <p>A Collapsible:</p>
    <button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

    <p>Collapsible Set:</p>
    <button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <button class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <button class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

  <script>
    var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
      coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.maxHeight){
          content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
      });
    }
  </script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Please, could you point me in the direction of where I am going wrong as fairly new to coding - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I understood from your question that you need a nested accordion. You can find an example in bootstrap [here on codepen.](https://codepen.io/marklsanders/pen/OPZXXv)

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne">Collapsible Group Item #1
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body">Panel 1</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseTwo">Collapsible Group Item #2
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <h2>Heading</h2>
                            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion21">
                                <div class="panel">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion21" href="#collapseTwoOne">View details 2.1 &raquo;
                                    </a>
                                    <div id="collapseTwoOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                        <div class="panel-body">Details 1</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel ">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion21" href="#collapseTwoTwo">View details 2.2 &raquo;
                                    </a>
                                    <div id="collapseTwoTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                        <div class="panel-body">Details 2</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseThree">Collapsible Group Item #3
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThreeOne">Collapsible Group Item #3.1
                                        </a>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapseThreeOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                    <div class="panel-body">Panel 3.1</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThreeTwo">Collapsible Group Item #3.2
                                        </a>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapseThreeTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                    <div class="panel-body">Panel 3.2</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the example provided, but ideally I would like to get the exsisting code working correctly so that I can see where I was going wrong. Basically I tried wrapping one div around the other and whilst it drops to show the sub heading, it doesn't work when you click on it. Here is the link to the live code: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapsible_symbol